# Jacoco code coverage for dev stream from a test project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, code-coverage, jacoco

I have an requirement to do a code coverage in this case  I choosed Jacoco and i new to it . I need a solution to see the no of source code covered in a dev project , when i run my selenium test project .

To be more clear

I do have an selenium test project so whenever i run a selenium test , each test covers some scenario which is actually created in dev project which need to be captured .

To achieve this i created an Jenkins job , added a plugin in Jenkins for publishing jacoco coverage report wherein  I point to classes directory of dev project , and also source directory pointing to dev project
and path to exec files as **/target/**.exec

I tried running a selenium test to see the code coverage with respect to dev project.but although the coverage report of Jacoco jenkins plugin showed all the packages of dev project , it didn't show the no of lines covered in dev project .

I am not sure if this approach is correct, please guide me if there is any apt solution for implementing this.

Please let me if my question is not clear .Thanks in advance